# How to restrict the access to undefined class/instance variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Python allowing access to undefined class/instance variable

I have defined a simple/empty python class as below. Now if I set a value for an undefined variable either with an instance variable or with class name, Python freely allows me to set the value for undefined variable and also allows me to access it like a instance or class variable without throwing any error. So in a nut shell, I am able to set undefined instance & class variables without any issues.

1. How do we restrict users from setting undefined instance and class variables in Python.
2. Here, how does Python treat these undefined variables (`undefined_variable_1` and `undefined_variable_2`)? Are these treated as instance variable or class variable or something else?

```
class Test:

  pass

### #Now instantiate the class and try setting & it accessing undefined variables
t1 = Test()

t1.undefined_variable_1 = "Undefined class/instance variable being set through instance variable (t1)"

### #Access the undefined variable through instance variable
print(t1.undefined_variable_1) 

Test.undefined_variable_2 = "Undefined class/instance variable being set through Class name (Test)"

### #Access the undefined variable through Class name
print(Test.undefined_variable_2)
```

How do we restrict user from setting/accessing undefined instance/instance variable?

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain why you want to do that? What's the problem with it?

Comment: This is how it **always works** in Python. variables, rather attributes in this case, don't exist *until you assign to them*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I suspect what they really want is to prevent code outside the class from creating new attributes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - The behavior is same even if I initialize other instance attributes through __init__() method and set undefined variables like in my example. If Python allows us to use undefined attributes w.r.t. a custom class, then how does it supports encapsulation? Kindly clarify.

Comment: @VivekN Python is built on the philosophy that we're all consenting adults here. You don't prevent people from doing potentially scary things; you tell them the situations that your class is meant to handle, and if they want to poke around in its internals and possibly cause chaos, that's on them. Even the `__slots__` method, which I mentioned in my answer, has the primary objective of *saving memory*.

Comment: @VivekN `__init__` holds no special status. It works *exactly the same way in `__init__`*. If by "encapsulation" you mean access modifiers, Python doesn't support that. Of course, it does support encapsulation in the broader sense of "bundling data with the operations that operate on that data".

Comment: @Barmar well, there probably is not way to accomplish that which isn't overwrought and probably will be easily subvertable anyway.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What about the `__slots__` solution in the answer? It seems to be exactly what the OP asked for. It might be subvertible, but it should prevent inadvertent attribute creation.

Comment: @Barmar you can still assign outside the class with `__slots__` as well. I tend to use slots to prevent *accidental* errors, like `obj.mt_var = <something>` instead of `obj.my_var = <something>`, although, ever since I started using `mypy` i've not needed that. Generally, I simply avoid interfaces that would require you to do that in the first place. So `my_obj.attribute = whatever` *always* looks wrong :)

Comment: So the answer is wrong? Usually the purpose of this kind of thing is to catch typos, not to prevent deliberate code.

Comment: @Barmar I would say the question is poorly specified. I can see how your interpretation makes sense, but as it stands, the question is vague

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - The answer from Barmar is useful. Between I am not sure what is vague in the question as below?                                                             How do we restrict users from setting undefined instance and class variables in Python.
Here, how does Python treat these undefined variables (undefined_variable_1 and undefined_variable_2)? Are these treated as instance variable or class variable or something else?

Comment: @Vivek.N because, **in Python you always set an attribute that isn't defined**. You must mean something like "how to prevent setting an attribute that isn't defined in the class definition statement" or "how to prevent the setting of attribute outside a specified range of names". Because, again, variables (attributes) do *not exist until they are assigned to*. Python does not have variable declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose, you can set `__slots__`, which constrains the attributes that an instance of a class can have:

```
class Restricted:

    __slots__ = ('a', 'b')

r = Restricted()
r.a = 1  # okay
r.b = 2  # okay
r.c = 3  # error
```

If you want to have the same functionality for the *class object*, you can create a custom metaclass and override `__setattr__`:

```
class RestrictedMeta(type):

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr in ('a', 'b'):
            super().__setattr__(attr, value)

        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Can't assign to attribute '{attr}' of class 'Restricted'")

class Restricted(metaclass=RestrictedMeta):
    pass

Restricted.a = 1  # okay
Restricted.b = 2  # okay
Restricted.c = 3  # error
```

Comment: @VivekN Yes, I noted that in my answer. You need a custom metaclass for that, which I have provided an example of.